# How to deal with a flat but "distorted" surface

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

I have a selected flat surface as shown on the right picture. Now I want to create this flat surface which should fit the main area.

When I connect the edges from the geometry and turn these 4 selected edges into my "flat" face, my flat face gets kinda distorted a bit, and it looks odd. (left image)

Does someone knows how to prevent this or doing it in a more efficent and better way?
Or should I deal with this as its not possible to fix?

Would appreciate helpful answers. :)

Thanks in Advance

[image: so the face on the left shouldn't be distorted like in my case.]

Comment: Have you tried knife? What else have you tried?

Comment: But what will a knife bring me? and how should I cut it?

I have tried on a different area (same problem there) adding many loop cuts.. but that didn't solved the problem. It also looks that odd as on this area shown above.

Comment: As Jag JB says, if the 4 vertices are not coplanar, it can't end up with a plane, to make it flat you can for example select the normal orientation in the Trnasform Orientations panel and flat on Z

Answer (score 1):

It seems your 4 vertices are not coplanar and therefore the face ends up distorted.

To improve things, you could use local coordinates and scale the plane in its normal direction to 0.
Something like a s-z-z-0 keyboard sequence from what I see on your left image.

But in any case, you will have to fix some parts of your geometry in order to connect everything and still get a plane.

Comment: Okay thank you then. will try to somehow edit the mesh by still matching the image, to get a flat surface. :)